# condition on segue identifier in protocol

Tags: ios, swift, segue, protocols

I have two view controllers 1st name is `ViewController` and 2nd Name is `ContactVC`. I have 3 buttons on 1st viewcontroller when i click on a button open 2nd viewController. In 2nd view controller i open phone contacts when i select any contact that contact name should be set as a button title. I have done with 1st button but from 2nd and 3rd button it does not works. Below is the code of 1st ViewController

```
import UIKit
import ContactsUI

class ViewController: UIViewController,CNContactPickerDelegate {
@IBOutlet weak var con1: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var con2: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var con3: UIButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if segue.identifier == "Contact1Segue"
    {
        (segue.destination as! ContactVC).delegate = self


    }

    else if segue.identifier == "Contact2Segue"
    {
        (segue.destination as! ContactVC).delegate = self
    }
    else if segue.identifier == "Contact3Segue"
    {
        (segue.destination as! ContactVC).delegate = self
    }
}

func findContacts() -> [CNContact]
{

    let store = CNContactStore()

    let keysToFetch = [CNContactFormatter.descriptorForRequiredKeys(for: .fullName),
                       CNContactImageDataKey,
                       CNContactPhoneNumbersKey] as [Any]

    let fetchRequest = CNContactFetchRequest(keysToFetch: keysToFetch as! [CNKeyDescriptor])

    var contacts = [CNContact]()

    do {
        try store.enumerateContacts(with: fetchRequest, usingBlock: { ( contact, stop) -> Void in
            contacts.append(contact)
        })
    }
    catch let error as NSError {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
    return contacts
}


func contactPickerDidCancel(picker: CNContactPickerViewController)
{
    print("Cancel Contact Picker")
}
}

extension ViewController: ContactVCDelegate
{

func updateData(data: String)
{
   self.con1.setTitle(data, for: .normal)
    self.con2.setTitle(data, for: .normal)
    self.con3.setTitle(data, for: .normal)

}
}
```

Below is the 2nd ViewController Code

```
import UIKit
import ContactsUI

class ContactVC: UIViewController, CNContactPickerDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

var contacts = [CNContact]()
var Name:String?
var delegate: ContactVCDelegate?

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async
        {
            let a = ViewController()
            self.contacts = a.findContacts()

            OperationQueue.main.addOperation
                {
                    self.tableView!.reloadData()
            }
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    print("Count:\(self.contacts.count)")
    return self.contacts.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if indexPath.row == 0
    {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SearchRID", for: indexPath)
        return cell
    }
    else
    {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CellRID", for: indexPath)
        let contact = contacts[indexPath.row] as CNContact
        cell.textLabel!.text = "\(contact.givenName) \(contact.familyName)"
        return cell
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("section:\(indexPath.section), row:\(indexPath.row)")

    let allcontact = self.contacts[indexPath.row] as CNContact
    Name = allcontact.givenName + allcontact.familyName


    self.delegate?.updateData(data: Name!)
    print("Name:\(Name)")
    _ = self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

//MARK:- CNContactPickerDelegate Method

func contactPicker(_ picker: CNContactPickerViewController, didSelect contacts: [CNContact]) {
    contacts.forEach({contact in
        for number in contact.phoneNumbers
        {
            let phonenum = number.value as CNPhoneNumber
            print("NUmber is = \(phonenum)")
        }
    })
}


}

protocol ContactVCDelegate
{
    func updateData(data: String)
}
```

Comment: Do you want to set same data on all of the three buttons?

Comment: no i want to set different data

Comment: Check your segue identifiers are correct. And when calling delegate methods from `didSelect` of `tableView`, check whether `delegate` is `nil` or not.

Comment: all is correct and delegate is not till

Comment: You only have one delegate method that is putting the same data on all thre buttons. When you say the second and third button "don't work", do you mean that the second view controller isn't shown or the buttons data isn't set?

Comment: buttons data set but all button data is same i want to set different dat on all the three buttons

Comment: @ArchanaSIngh check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your protocol:

```
protocol ContactVCDelegate
{
    func updateData(buttonId:int, data: String)
}
```

Have a field in your second view controller with buttonId.
And set this value while preparing segue:

```
(segue.destination as! ContactVC).buttonId = 1
```

Your Update function:

```
func updateData(buttonId:int, data: String)
{
  switch(buttonId){
case 1:
 self.con1.setTitle(data, for: .normal)
break

case 2:
 self.con2.setTitle(data, for: .normal)
break

 case 3:
 self.con3.setTitle(data, for: .normal)
 break
}


}
```

In second view controller, onDidSelect:

```
self.delegate?.updateData(buttonId:buttonId,data: Name!)
```

Comment: i declared var buttonID : Int? in second controller but does not work

Comment: What are are you getting? Please give more details. You should set (segue.destination as! ContactVC).buttonId = 1
 for each button with different values. Like 2 for second button and 3 for third button.

Comment: yes i do that. but data not set on the button title

Comment: okay. let's do little debugging. Apply breakpoint on switch in updateData and check whether you are getting correct value or not.

Comment: Its Working Fine Thanks a lot . Actually i thought remove delegate and add buttonID but its work with both. Thanks Dear @Sac

Comment: Happy to help :)